# Postgres not using expression index

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-9.5, regular-expression, query-performance

I am using Postgres 9.5. It is possible this is related to the changes in 9.6 pointed out by [PostgreSQL not using index during count(*)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126997/postgresql-not-using-index-during-count/128445#128445), but I cannot be sure yet.

I have a table that has a `character varying` column called `text`. I am attempting to optimize queries which have to perform a regex on this column.

This often looks like

```
select * from table where text ~ 'some|key|words|we|want';
```

or the inverse

```
select * from table where text !~ 'some|key|words|we|want';
```

sometimes in joins

```
select category, count(*)
from other_t join table on (other_t.table_id = table.id)
where table.text ~ 'some|key|words|we|want';

select category, count(*)
from other_t join
    (select id
     from table
     where table.text ~ 'some|key|words|we|want') as ti on (other_t = ti.id);
```

Notice that the regex is always the same.

I do not want to index the column directly because AFAIK indexing text columns results in a relatively huge index that would just be a waste of space. This rules out a partial index per the linked post above. So, I've been trying to use an expression index, which I should be able to do because the regex is always the same.

*However, I can't get Postgres to use the index!*

I've done a `vacuum analyze`, I've tried every type of query I can imagine, but it always just does a `Seq Scan`.

The column averages ~85 characters and typically only has one or two of the keywords we're looking for if it is a match.

Any ideas?

I am not interested in full keyword search. We have a finite, stable list of words we're looking for. I don't want to make an enormous trigram/ts_vector index on this text column when all I really need is an expression index that Postgres decides to use.

We cannot eliminate the text column because it has other uses. We have already thought of adding a column which is essentially a cache of this query, but that's just ugly. If that is the best option, so be it, but we *really* should be able to use an index here.

#### Index Creation

```
create index text_col_idx on table ((text ~ 'some|key|words|we|want'));
```

#### Explain Analyze

```
explain (analyze, verbose) select id from table where text ~ 'some|key|words|we|want';
```

#### Results

```
Seq Scan on public.table  (cost=0.00..405624.24 rows=5190575 width=4) (actual time=0.113..52582.259 rows=5113014 loops=1)
  Output: id
  Filter: ((table.text)::text ~ 'some|key|words|we|want'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 4728206
Planning time: 10.938 ms
Execution time: 52766.607 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Your condition only eliminates about 50% of the rows in the table. In that case the Seq Scan will be faster than the Index Scan.

See for example [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203827), where user [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) says:

> If the `SELECT` returns more than approximately 5-10% of all rows in the table, a sequential scan is much faster than an index scan.
>
> This is because an index scan requires *several* IO operations for each row (look up the row in the index, then retrieve the row from the heap). Whereas a sequential scan only requires a single IO  for each row - or even less because a block (page) on the disk contains more than one row, so more than one row can be fetched with a single IO operation.

Also see [Index-Only Scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) in the documentation, which includes:

> In principle, index-only scans can be used with expression indexes. [...] However, PostgreSQL's planner is currently not very smart about such cases. It considers a query to be potentially executable by index-only scan only when all ***columns*** needed by the query are available from the index.

A separate idea would be to have a `keywords` table alongside your main one, with one ID per word you are interested in, and an ID related to a specific text, and just populate it as needed. The choice will obviously depend on many other constraints that only you can know.

Comment: I did succeed in optimizing the query by creating an additional index on the group-column (which I neglected to add the `group by` in my question...), which aligns with what you're saying. Thank you!